# Custom directive dom not change when parent scope make changes using {{}} with @ attribute

Tags: angularjs, custom-directive

I am creating a custom directive with isolate scope using interpolation ({{}}) from parent scope, should be when parent scope is change the attribute should be updated with the new data. i have only 1 data been changed, the other is not change.

i dont need 2 way binding just 1 way binding is enough that is why i am using @ as an attribute property.

my parent html

```
<button ng-click="testClick()">Test Click</button>
<my-directive ng-repeat="sensor in sensors track by sensor.sensor_name" 
sensor-name="{{ sensor.sensor_name }}" display-name="{{sensor.display_name}}" 
state-normal="{{ sensor.stateNormal }}" state-alert="{{ sensor.stateAlert }}" 
state-total="{{ sensor.total }}"></my-directive>
```

my directive template

```
<div>
  <span>{{ displayName }}</span>
</div>
<div>
  Normal
</div>
<div>
  {{ states["Normal"] }}
</div>
<div>
   Alert
</div>
<div>
   {{ states["Alert"] }}
</div>
<div>
  Total
</div>
<div>
    {{ states["Total"] }}
</div>
```

inside my parent scope

```
$scope.sensors = [{
  sensor_name: "stre",
  display_name: "Stre"
}];

var initState = {
  normal: "0",
  alert: "0"
};

var setInitState = function(sensors) {
  for (let i = 0; i < sensors.length; i++) {
    sensors[i]["stateNormal"] = "0";
    sensors[i]["stateAlert"] = "0";
    sensors[i]["total"] = "0";
  }
  return sensors;
}

$scope.sensors = setInitState($scope.sensors);

$scope.testClick = function() {
  $scope.sensors[0].display_name = "testchange";
  $scope.sensors[0].stateNormal = "15";
  $scope.sensors[0].total = "38";
}
```

my directive scope

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.states = {
                "Normal": $scope.stateNormal ? $scope.stateNormal : 'x',
                "Alert": $scope.stateAlert ? $scope.stateAlert : 'x',
                "Total": $scope.stateTotal ? $scope.stateTotal : 'x'
            };
        },
        templateUrl: "my-directive.php",
        scope: {
            sensorName: '@',
            displayName: '@',
            stateNormal: '@',
            stateAlert: '@',
            stateTotal: '@'
        }
    };
 });
```

the button click is expecting changes towards all the value, but when the button click only the display_name is change but normal and total value is not changing.

you can refer to this plunkr: https://embed.plnkr.co/aXctKP/

Answer (score 0):

you can check out this [working plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/FaX21a9KnYDnOPc5).

You can check out [angularjs docs here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/guide/directive) to better understand how directive work.

What I do to make it right is I rename the variable inside `my-directive.php` to follow the attribute you have set in the `index.html`. You can read the angularjs doc under the Normalization section, it says that it will normalize the element's attribute from `state-total` to `stateTotal`.